Proving that an arrow in a diagram is an isomorphism.
The following commutative diagram is from Sheaves in Geometry and Logic by Mac Lane and Moerdijk, Proposition II.2.2. We know that $\beta, \gamma$ are isomorphisms, $a$ is the equalizer of $b,c$; $d$ is the equalizer of $e, f$. The right square commutes in the sense that the squares with $b$ at the top, $e$ at the bottom; $c$ at the top, $f$ at the bottom commute.
The authors claim that it is an easy exercise to check that this implies that $\alpha$ is also an isomorphism. I am not sure that my explanation to this is correct.
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\text{Hom}(\mathbf{y}U, E) @>{a}>> \text{Hom}(\mathbf{y}U, F) @>{b,c}>> \text{Hom}(\mathbf{y}U, G)\\
@V{\alpha}VV @V{\beta}VV @V{\gamma}VV\\
\text{Hom}(S, E) @>{d}>> \text{Hom}(S, F) @>{e,f}>> \text{Hom}(S, G)\\
\end{CD}
Attempt. We prove that $\alpha$ is monic (since these are sets this is equivalent to injectivity), and that there is a monic arrow from $\text{Hom}(S, E)$ to $\text{Hom}(\mathbf{y}U, E)$, which together implies that $\alpha$ is an isomorphism.
$\alpha$ Monic. Suppose that $f, g \in \text{Hom}(\mathbf{y}U, E)$ such that $\alpha(f) = \alpha(g)$. Then, since
$$a = \beta^{-1} \circ d \circ \alpha$$
We have that $a(f) = a(g)$, but since $a$ is an equalizer, thus monic, and $f=g$.
Isomorphism. Using that both $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are isomorphisms, the composite $\beta^{-1} \circ d$ equalizes $b$ and $c$. By universality, there is an arrow $x: \text{Hom}(S, U) \to \text{Hom}(\mathbf{y}U, E)$, which is monic, since $\beta^{-1} \circ d$, and $a$ are monic. But then then there are monic arrows in both directions between $\text{Hom}(\mathbf{y}U, E)$ and $\text{Hom}(S, E)$, and hence $\alpha$ is an isomorphism.
Questions. Firstly, is my proof correct? Secondly, is this the easy proof that the authors were referring to?

As a hint, you may want to abstract from that specific example and write down the general fact about equalizers. So, get rid of these hom-sets. And then you can also generalize and prove that equalizers are functorial in a certain sense. In fact, all limits are. And functors preserve isomorphisms.

Firstly, could you confirm if the current solution is correct? I am happy to move on to a new solution, but if this is flawed, I'd like to correct it first.
Secondly, upon omitting the hom-sets, and retaining all notation, using that $\beta \circ a$ equalizes $e$ and $f$, by universality I can prove that $\alpha$ is monic. The second part of my proof still goes through. Is this what you mean?

The proof is not correct. If $X,Y$ are sets and there are monics $i : X \to Y$, $j : Y \to X$, this does not guarantee that $i$ is an isomorphism. Consider $i,j : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ with $i(n)=n + 1$ and $j(n) = n$.
I strongly recommend to abstract from that specific example and instead prove a more general statement in any category. This has several advantages.

It is more general and thus applies to more contexts. You will be able to use it in many other situations.
The proof cannot possibly use stuff from the specific example which is not relevant, thus is easier to find. Everything you need to use is right in front of you!
It is a good training how to work in categories, not just with sets as in your specific example, which often puts too much emphasis on elements.

General statement
In any category, assume that we have a commutative* diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
E @>{i}>> A @>{f}>{g}> B \\ @. @V{a}VV @VV{b}V \\ E' @>>{i'}> A' @>{f'}>{g'}> B'\end{CD}$$
*By commutative, I mean that $bf = f'a$ and $bg = g'a$.
Assume that $i$ is the equalizer of $f,g$, and likewise $i'$ is the equalizer of $f',g'$.
Claim. There is a unique morphism $e : E \to E'$ such that the square
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
E @>{i}>> A \\ @V{e}VV @VV{a}V \\ E' @>>{i'}> A' \end{CD}$$
commutes. Moreover, if $a$ and $b$ are isomorphisms, then $e : E \to E'$ is an isomorphism as well.
The proof is straight forward. You only need to use the definitions of the notions involed (category, isomorphism, equalizer). It is also useful (but that is an immediate consequence of the definition) to know that $i$ and $i'$ are monomorphisms.
Please try to find the proof yourself before checking the proof below.
Proof that $e$ exists and is unique.

 The morphism $ai : E \to A'$ equalizes $f',g'$, because $f'ai = bfi = bgi = g'ai$. Hence, since $i'$ is the equalizer of $f',g'$, there is a unique morphism $e : E \to E'$ with $ai = i'e$.

Proof that $e$ is an isomorphism when $a,b$ are

 By assumption, there are inverse morphisms $a^{-1},b^{-1}$. Then, we have the following commutative diagram $$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} E' @>{i'}>> A' @>{f'}>{g'}> B \\ @. @V{a^{-1}}VV @VV{b^{-1}}V \\ E @>>{i}> A @>{f}>{g}> B\end{CD}$$ By what we have already proven before, there must be a unique morphism $e' : E' \to E$ such that $ie' = a^{-1} i'$. We need to show that $e'$ is inverse to $e$. We compute $ie'e = a^{-1} i'e = a^{-1} a i = i = i \, \mathrm{id}_E$. Since $i$ is a monomorphism, we conclude $e'e = \mathrm{id}_E$. Exactly in the same way we conclude $ee' = \mathrm{id}_{E'}$.

Generalization to limits
All of this is a special case of a much more general lemma: If $\mathcal{J}$ is an index category, $F,F' : \mathcal{J} \to \mathcal{C}$ two diagrams in $\mathcal{C}$ of shape $\mathcal{J}$ (i.e., functors) which have limits $\lim(F),\lim(F')$, and $\alpha : F \to F'$ is a morphism of functors, then it induces a unique morphism $\lim(\alpha) : \lim(F) \to \lim(F')$ such that for all $i \in \mathcal{J}$ the diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\lim(F) @>{\lim(\alpha)}>> \lim(F') \\ @VVV @VVV \\ F(i) @>>{\alpha(i)}> F'(i) \end{CD}$$
commutes. Moreover, if $\alpha$ is an isomorphism, then $\lim(\alpha)$ is an isomorphism as well. Actually, this follows abstractly from $\lim(\mathrm{id}) = \mathrm{id}$ and $\lim(\beta \alpha) = \lim(\beta) \lim(\alpha)$.

Thanks, I see what you mean. Essentially my mistake seems to be the fact that a monomorphism between isomorphic objects is not necessarily an isomorphism (which is quite obvious in hindsight...), but in this case $e$ is not any monomorphism.
